# How does Spark streaming and Dstream work?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, streaming, bigdata

I have fair bit of experience with Spark. However, I'm learning Spark streaming for the first time and finding it very hard to understand. Its difficult to understand the flow of application. For example, for the example given on the following site

http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/3/exercises/realtime-processing-with-spark-streaming.html

The code at part 3.Further Exercises, we have

```
val words = statuses.flatMap(status => status.split(" "))
val hashtags = words.filter(word => word.startsWith("#"))
val counts = hashtags.map(tag => (tag, 1))
                         .reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Seconds(60 * 5), Seconds(1))
```

Supposedly, its calculating the most popular twitter hash tags for the last 5 minutes. So, how is this working. Is there some kind of hidden loop which executes after every 5 minutes? Is the value in `words` and `hashtags`, after each second or 5 minutes? What is going on here? I am lost, please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can see `DStream` as an `RDD[RDD[T]]`. Every five minutes, a new `RDD` is going to be instantiated with all the data gathered during the last 5 minutes. You will then be able to process this `RDD` just like you would with any `RDD`. You have some additional methods allowing you to compute results over *windows* (each window containing a finite number of `RDD`s). When you apply a transformation to a `DStream`, the transformation is applied to all the sub-`RDD`s.

Here is an example of what happens when applying `map` to a `DStream`.

```
val stream: DStream 
                    \ 
                     RDD -- RDD -- RDD
stream.map
          \
           RDD.map -- RDD.map -- RDD.map
```

Comment: You mean variable words and hashtags will contain DStream for 5 seconds, represented by an RDD of subRDDs, where data for each second is represented by a subRDD, so the RDD would contain around 5 * 60 = 300 subRDDs. Secondly, Spark decided to keep data like this after it saw the line where variable counts is assigned with reduceByKeyAndWindow function. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Ok, let me read again the doc, I have not used Spark Streaming myself, I just have a high-lebel understanding from reading the part about streaming in the official book

Comment: Is your question specifically about `reduceByKeyAndByWindow` ? If so, I can help you about this.